# ubuntu 20.10 installer can't select installation type

Tags: boot, system-installation, toshiba-satellite, 20.10

I'm trying to erase win 10 and install Ubuntu 20.10 but the installer don't have the *"Erase disk and Install ubuntu"* option anymore and the installation gets to the *"Installation Type"* section that gives an error

[This was the old option but I can't find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71spA.png)

The laptop is a Toshiba Satellite E45t.
I'm booting from a USB, made the usb with Rufus.

Comment: Imagine Windows is using dynamic partition or is in fast boot shutdown(hibernation) and Ubuntu cannot see Windows.  Can use gparted from installer(try Ubuntu) to delete if you are sure.  All data will be lost unless you have backup.

Comment: Thanks!!! Life saver!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to crip659 for the help...

With gpart I gave a new format to the drive (Erasing everything) in order to establish a space for the Ubunto to be installed ...